Find nth key pair value from the JSON using SQL query
I have a JSON shown here, stored in a column of a SQL Server table:
{
  "Name": "oxygen",
  "StartDate": "2018-06-05",
  "EndDate": "2018-06-22",
  "Desc": {
    "quality": "better",
    "level,amount": "Scheduled",
    "05": "carbon",
    "GDP": "Max",
    "CDF": "ZENE 1",
    "OTBC": "REMO - MIXED UNIQUE"
  }
}

How to find the 5th key pair value using a T-SQL query?
I have tried this:
select JSON_QUERY(column_value,'$.Desc[5]') AS 'result' 
from table_name

select JSON_VALUE([column_value],'$.Desc[5]') as'result' 
from table_name

Expected result is "CDF": "ZENE 1".
Any help is appreciated.

Here I made an example using openjson but I am not sure if it will save the order every time you execute the query

Not sure there's an easy way, because key order isn't something that OPENJSON reports for json objects, but here's one idea:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY ID ORDER BY charindex('"' + [key] + '":', column_value)) AS sort
    ,   *
    FROM    (
        SELECT  N'{
      "Name": "oxygen",
      "StartDate": "2018-06-05",
      "EndDate": "2018-06-22",
      "Desc": {
        "quality": "better",
        "level,amount": "Scheduled",
        "05": "carbon",
        "GDP": "Max",
        "CDF": "ZENE 1",
        "OTBC": "REMO - MIXED UNIQUE"
      }
        }' AS column_value, 1 AS id
    ) x
    CROSS apply openjson(column_value, '$.Desc')
    ) x
WHERE   sort = 5

After splitting column_value by Desc keys, i use ROW_NUMBER to check the position of each key string inside the json string, and then use that as base to the counter that returns the fifth value.
The downside of this approach is that it uses string methods, which can be slow and somewhat brittle

It's probably the first option. One possible problem is escaped JSON content (... "\"CDF": "Max" ...).
