Dynamic SQL generation in SQL Server
I have to generate dynamic SQL query for inserting values to the below table from a JSON.
Eg: demo_table(id, key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
json - data = {"rows":[{"test_id":11,"score":100,"name":"test"}]}
The insert statement will be like below,
insert into demo_table(key1,key2,key3,value1,value2,value3)
values
("test_id",score,"name":11,"100":"test")`

Based on the number of elements in the JSON, the query has to dynamically adjust, since the max number of columns are key5 and value5, based on the number of JSON elements, the others columns can be set to null.
Anyone have any ideas on this one, I tried many options and found many errors on the way.
Any help would be really appreciated.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

OPENJSON

The real issue here is your design. You have violated 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. If you normalize your table structure this should be pretty simple.

Also, it seems that your JSON is not well-formed.

How do you know in which column slot the json value fits? ie, in your example, why aren't key4 and key5 populated. Is it always that number of key and values is the same? Not sure you've thought this through all the way. This design means you can't leave out the values.

@siggemannen the idea is keep the table as a template, the json would be an api response, based on the response data the table entries will be populated, the rest columns will be set to null.

You could use openjson to get a list of "columns" from a json row, unfortunately, there's no guarantee that keys are in particular order, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78370696/find-nth-key-pair-value-from-the-json-using-sql-query/78371110#78371110 for some mitigation. Then you can perhaps match it to the sys.tables / sys.columns columns

You can use ROW_NUMBER with a manual pivot (using conditional aggregation).
declare @data nvarchar(max) = N'{"rows":[{"test_id":11,"score":100,"name":"test"}]}';

insert into demo_table
  (key1, key2, key3, value1, value2, value3)
select
  min(case when j.rn = 1 then j.[key] end),
  min(case when j.rn = 2 then j.[key] end),
  min(case when j.rn = 3 then j.[key] end),
  min(case when j.rn = 1 then j.value end),
  min(case when j.rn = 2 then j.value end),
  min(case when j.rn = 3 then j.value end)
from (
    select j2.*,
      row_number() over (order by j1.[key], j2.[key]) as rn
    from openjson(@data, '$.rows') j1
    cross apply openjson(j1.value) j2
) j;

I strongly recommend you change your design. Either give the columns proper names (and remove the key columns), or normalize into rows.

Thanks @Charlieface, i tried this, however its not handling the dynamic case, in my scenario the  '(key1, key2, key3, value1, value2, value3)'  should generate dynamically based on the number of elements from the rows. do you think we can achieve it.

SQL is a static language, which expects the list of columns up front, not dynamically. You would need to generate a dynamic SQL statement to execute. Or you can just  generate enough columns to cover all cases. Maybe rethink your requirement?
